# Arc length of the squircle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, arc-length

The squircle is given by the equation $x^4+y^4=r^4$. Apparently, its circumference or arc length $c$ is given by

$$c=-\frac{\sqrt[4]{3} r G_{5,5}^{5,5}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},1,\frac{4}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{12},\frac{5}{12},\frac{7}{12},\frac{3}{4},\frac{13}{12} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{16 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{7/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$

Where $G$ is the *Meijer $G$ function*. Where can I find the derivation of this result? Searching for any combination of squircle and arc length or circumference has led to nowhere.

Comment: There's an eightfold symmetry you can exploit. Have you tried explicitly writing down the arc-length integral and seeing if you get the line integral definition of the Meijer G-function? (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Definition_of_the_Meijer_G-function)

Comment: The squircle is a special case of a super ellipse. The arc-length intergral of a super-ellipse has been calculated here in detail: http://fractional-calculus.com/super_ellipse.pdf They get some series, which if you are lucky coincides with that particular Meijer G-function.

Comment: @Mankind if you can distill the relevant parts of that pdf to an answer is gladly award you the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this empirical formula to find perimeter of general super-ellipse

$$L=a+b\times\left(\frac{2.5}{n+0.5}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\times \left( b+a\times(n-1)\times\frac{\frac{0.566}{n^2}}{b+a\times\left(\frac{4.5}{0.5+n^2}\right)}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

By your definition, $\mathcal{C} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^4 + y^4 = r^4\}$. Which can be parametrized as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C} =
\begin{cases}
\left(+\sqrt{\cos (\theta )},+\sqrt{\sin (\theta )} \right)r\\
\left(+\sqrt{\cos (\theta )},-\sqrt{\sin (\theta )} \right)r\\
\left(-\sqrt{\cos (\theta )},+\sqrt{\sin (\theta )} \right)r\\
\left(-\sqrt{\cos (\theta )},-\sqrt{\sin (\theta )} \right)r
\end{cases}
, \qquad 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, \, 0<r
\end{align}

[image]

Now, look at this curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$ as $y = \sqrt[4]{r^4-x^4}$, then observe that symmetry with both axis. It yields the arc length is just: 
$$c = 4 \int_{0}^{r} \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{r^4-x^4}\right)^2} \,dx = 4 \int_{0}^{r} \sqrt{1+\frac{x^6}{\left(r^4-x^4\right)^{3/2}}} \,dx$$

Comment: In the image, $r=1$

Comment: Actually, the curve has eight-fold symmetry along the lines $x^2 = y^2$. We can therefore also take an arc sweep of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and multiply that value by $8$.

Comment: Perfect addition, @JackLam.

Comment: I have done this, but I still don't see how this is equivalent to the stated result.